# Bootstrap dropdown on BlackBerry

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, blackberry-10, blackberry-playbook

I have realized the standard dropdown menus in Bootstrap does not work on BlackBerry devices (OS 10). Even not on older BlackBerry Playbook.
I can click on the button, it shows it was pressed but the dropdown menu does not appear.

Weird is when I open the bootstrap main site of Bootstrap with my BB Q10 the getbootstrap.com the dropdown menus are working fine but when I open the example pages they do not. So clearly there is a workaround for this.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new update of BlackBerry 10 OS 10.2.1.2102 solved the issue.
The dropdowns, the collapse-navbar, modals, popups, tooltips and basically everything with JavaScript is working now fine.